# Can I use an American key from Amazon in my Origin client which is identified as British?

Tags: battlefield-3, origin

I live in Israel, when buying a game from Steam I pay in USD and pay the American price. I want to buy Battlefield 3 but Origin identifies me as British and asks me to pay the more expensive British price.

I'm using a single use credit card so refund isn't much of an option in case it doesn't work.

Can I buy the American download version from Amazon (or someone American will buy it for me) and register the American key with Origin?

Has anyone tried it?

Comment: I think you can, but I'm not 100% sure, you should buy it from a UK store

Comment: @pixel slow down! You're destroying the homepage!

Answer (score 4):

Just went with it. You can buy it from Amazon and redeem anywhere, but I wanted to add that Amazon suggests you download the game from them (it offers a downloader), but it kept disconnecting.

Your serial number is in your personal downloads page, use it in Origin and download at 1MB\s.

Answer (score 1):

Yes -- the game is universal and all keys work in any country.

(Changing the default language in the game away from English, I don't know about, but presumably that can be done via game settings somewhere.)